# Euler characteristic is the alternating sum of dimensions of the homology

Tags: algebraic-topology

> Give a direct proof that Euler characteristic is the alternating sum of dimensions of the homology, using the rank of the boundary maps.

This is my instructor's question of today's topology class. But I am really confused about this question because this is exactly the definition of Euler characteristic. Can somebody please tell me what exactly I have to show here?

Comment: There are other possible definitions, e.g. as the alternating sum of the number of $n$-simplices/cells. Did your instructor give an alternate definition?

Comment: Ok thanks. I think I mixed up with homology and simplicies.